# Flash message not showing because of conditon

Tags: flask

In flask, im trying to flash a message when there are no results from the user's search. Problem is, the flash is not doing its job. I believe its because of the if condition but im not sure why.

If i make this the condition: if counter == 0: then flash , it works. But even when the user is just reloading the search page, the message gets flashed so its not desirable. That why im trying to create the condition based on book.query & this is where im stuck.

```
@app.route("/search", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    keyword = escape(request.form.get("keyword"))
    books = Book.query.filter(or_(Book.isbn.like(f'%{keyword}%'), Book.title.like(
        f'%{keyword}%'), Book.author.like(f'%{keyword}%'))).all()
    counter = Book.query.filter(or_(Book.isbn.like(f'%{keyword}%'), Book.title.like(
        f'%{keyword}%'), Book.author.like(f'%{keyword}%'))).count()

    if books is None:
        flash('No matches found!', 'info')

    return render_template('search.html', title='Search', books=books)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query for books you use `.all()` at the end.

`.all()` returns a list - in case of no result, this will be an empty list, but you compare the result to `None`.

While both `None` and `[]` are falsy values, they are not identical.

But you explicitly compare object identity with the `is` keyword.

So you could change your if guard to

```
if not books:
```

or

```
if len(books) == 0:
```

Make sure to tell us how it worked out!